# Does removing hot network questions on a SE site increase participation on that SE site?

Tags: discussion, hot-questions, participation

I've noticed a hot network question (HNQ) was removed from the list of HNQs, the rationale being it'll increase participation (= more views, more answers, more comments, more votes) on this SE site by forcing the HNQ algorithm to rotate to new ones (=select new HNQs).

Does removing a hot network question from time to time on a SE site increase participation on this SE site?

Comment: I don't imagine anyone has done research on how often hot network questions should be cycled out to produce maximum benefit. Currently, they can only be on the list for up to 3 days, so actively removing them sooner in hopes of increasing traffic seems like an extremely minimal benefit, if any. There's no guarantee that slot would even be filled with another question from that site, so the chance of losing traffic is probably just as high.

Comment: Interesting thing would be to experiment with this. Wonder how large your sample would need to be in order to determine any (statistically significant) effect.

Comment: "*the rationale being it'll increase participation (= more views, more answers, more comments, more votes) on this SE site by forcing the HNQ algorithm to rotate to new ones (=select new HNQs).*" citation needed? Most of the time I saw, it's used to prevent controversial/bad questions from getting more exposure and moderation issues.

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. I don't want to single out a mod.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt how is that even related? Andrew means your basic assumption here might be wrong, and the questions are removed from HNQ for different reasons than what you claim here, which I also agree with.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard the reason was stated by a mod. I prefer not to cite the mod since I don't intend to make a personal.

Comment: Well if it was said in public (chat, comment, etc. on some SE site) then just post link, it's public anyway. If said to you in private, well, you have a point. Still, never seen such a case, which of course doesn't mean it never happens, but most of the removal  cases are most likely to prevent unfitting questions from staying in the HNQ.